# using sum over partition in SQL Server Report Builder

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder

I have a view that joins customers and their orders, the columns are as follows:

```
CustomerId   Gender    OrderNo    OrderDate   OrderYear   OrderMonth   OrderQuarter
====================================================================================
```

When given a date, the report is supposed to extract the date parts (Year, Quarter, Month) and query this view to give a matrix that looks like this:

```
                          NoOfCustomersForTheMonth    NoOfCustomersForTheQuarter    NoOfCustomerForTheYear
===========================================================================================================
New Customers    MALE         20                              100                         400
                 FEMALE       30                              200                         500
TOTAL                         50                              300                         900
```

Is this possible without making changes to the view? I hope my explanation is clear enough. I also apologize if someone else has answered this, kindly point me in the right direction, and I will owe you my life :)

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot see what your data looks like, you should be able to produce this report using an aggregate function and a `CASE` expression:

```
select gender,
  count(case when OrderMonth = 1 then CustomerId end) NoCustomersForMonth,
  count(case when OrderQuarter = 1 then CustomerId end) NoCustomersForQuarter,
  count(case when OrderYear = 2013 then CustomerId end) NoCustomersForYear
from yourview
group by gender
```

Inside of the `CASE` you will replace the value of the `OrderMonth`, `OrderQuarter` and `OrderYear` with the values that you need